# How to add arguments to $@ without splitting the space-containing arguments that are already there?

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

My goal is to encapsulate the svn command to provide additional features. Here is a minimal (not) working example of the function used to do that:

```
function custom_svn {
    newargs="$@ my_additional_arg"
    svn $newargs
}
```

But this does not work with arguments containing spaces. For instance when called like this:

```
message="my commit text"
custom_svn ci some_file.txt -m "$message"
```

SVN tries to commit `some_file.txt`, `commit` and `text`, with the message "my" instead of committing only `some_file.txt` with message "my commit text".

I guess the issue lies in the erroneous use of $@, but I'm not sure how to proceed to keep the message whole.

Comment: It won't split the space containing arguments if it's quoted though, they will still be space separated, you would need them to be quoted to be seen as a single argument to svn though.

Answer (score 4):

In standard sh, the positional arguments are the only sort of array you've got. You can append to them with `set`:

```
set -- "$@" my_additional_arg
svn "$@"
```

In bash, you can create your own custom array variables too:

```
newargs=("$@" my_additional_arg)
svn "${newargs[@]}"
```

Of course, as DigitalRoss answered, in your specific example you can avoid using a variable entirely, but I'll guess that your example is a bit oversimplified.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
svn "$@" my_additional_arg
```

The problem is that the construct `"$@"` is special only in that exact form.

It's interesting, this brings up the whole good-with-the-bad nature of shell programming. Because it's a macro processor, it's much easier to write simple things in bash than in full languages. But, it's harder to write complex things, because every time you try to go a level deeper in abstraction you need to change your code to properly expand the macros in the new level of evaluation.